# rewriting a file using function fprint and an int array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to overwrite a file with the contents of an int array using fprintf. This should be a very simple program, however, I'm not getting the expected output. Please don't suggest using another function since this is a uni assignment and we must use arrays and fprintf.

So while I'm expecting the file to contain:

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

I'm getting:

```
1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 
1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 1495894796 1495894796
```

And this compiler warning:

```
  format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
```

I don't know what can be causing this error, since I have a very similar program that works well, but in which I use a char array instead, and the function fputc.

Here is the relevant part of my code, feel free to ask for the complete code if necessary:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    #define ARRAY_ELEMENTS 13
    /* Defining the size of my int array */

    int main(){
      int i, aux;
      FILE *finformation
      int defined_array[ARRAY_ELEMENTS];

      i = 0;

      while (i < (ARRAY ELEMENTS - 1))
      {
          defined_array[i] = 3;
          i = i+1;
      }
      defined_array[i] = 999;
      /* This should initialize my int array with all the numbers
      being 3 but the last one being 999 */

      finformation = fopen("/Users/(path here)/file.txt", "w");
      /* I'm pretty sure I didn't screw up here because the file does
      get overwritten */

      i = 0;
      aux = defined_array[i];
      /* I want to read the first number in the int array 
      and store it in an int variable: aux. Here is where I've
      probably messed up things */

      while (aux != 999)
      {
          fprintf(finformation,"%d ", &aux);
          i = i+1;
          aux = defined_array[i];
      }
      /* While I don't read the last number in my int array (999), I  
      want to write the last read number into the file. Then, leave
      an space and repeat */

      fclose(finformation);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `&` in front of the `aux` in the `fprintf` call.

Simply use

```
fprintf(finformation, "%d ", aux);
```

The `&` is changing the type form `int` to `int*` (pointer to the integer).

Answer (score 2):

Remove `&` from the statement

```
fprintf(finformation,"%d ", &aux);  
                  //        ^ Remove & operator
```

Otherwise program's behavior will be undefined.